# Tracing original Value through Iteration SQL

Tags: sql, recursion

Suppose there is a data collection system that, whenever a record is altered, it is then saved as a new record with a prefix (say M-[most recent number in que and is unique]).

Suppose I am given the following data set:

```
 Customer    |         Original_Val
    1                  1020
    2                  1011
    3                  1001
```

I need to find the most recent value for each customer given the following table:

```
 Customer    |    Most_Recent_Val     |    Pretained_To_Val    |     date
    1                  M-2000                   M-1050             20170225
    1                  M-1050                   M-1035             20170205
    1                  M-1035                    1020              20170131
    1                   1020                     NULL              20170101
    2                  M-1031                    1011              20170105
    2                   1011                     NULL              20161231
    3                   1001                     NULL              20150101
```

My desired output would be:

```
 Customer    |    Original_Val     |    Most_Recent_Val    |     date
    1                 1020                   M-2000             20170225
    2                 1011                   M-1031             20170105
    3                 1001                   1001               20150101
```

For customer 1, there are 4 levels i.e (M-2000 <- M-1050 <- M-1035 <- 1020) Note that there would be no more than 10 levels of depth for each customer.

Much Appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Find the min and max of each customer and then join it together. Something like this:

```
Select
    [min].Customer
    ,[min].Most_Recent_Val as Original_Val
    ,[max].Most_Recent_Val as Most_Recent_Val
    ,[max].date
From
    (
        Select
            Customer
            ,Most_Recent_Val
            ,date
        From
            table t1
            inner join (
                Select
                    Customer
                    ,MIN(date) as MIN_Date
                From
                    table
                Group By
                    Customer
            ) t2 ON t2.Customer = t1.Customer
                and t2.MIN_Date = t1.Date
    ) [min]
    inner join (
        Select
            Customer
            ,Most_Recent_Val
            ,date
        From
            table t1
            inner join (
                Select
                    Customer
                    ,MAX(date) as MAX_Date
                From
                    table
                Group By
                    Customer
            ) t2 ON t2.Customer = t1.Customer
                and t2.MAX_Date = t1.Date
    ) [max] ON [max].Customer = [min].Customer
```